# Find most occurrences in multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4  
A,B,C,C  
B,D,D,D  
C,C,A,C  
B,B,D,D
```

I want to find the most occurences for all four answers, if the number of occurrences are the same, I just need the first value. So ideally I should have a output table like this:

```
Answer1,Answer2,Answer3,Answer4,MostAnswers,Occurrences  
A,B,C,C,C,2  
B,D,D,D,D,3  
C,C,A,C,C,3  
B,B,D,D,B,2
```

How can I do this in sql server? Can I do a group by across column by row?

Comment: You're looking for sequence of LETTERS or the most common LETTER for each answer?

Comment: does your table have a primary key, or just the Answer1-4 columns?

Comment: I can have the primary key for this, but I think the pivoting is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach, that still assumes the presence of an `Id` column:

```
select 
  a.Id,
  a.Answer1, 
  a.Answer2, 
  a.Answer3, 
  a.Answer4,
  TopAnswers.*
from AnswerTable a
outer apply (
  select top 1 Answer, count(*) as cnt
  from (
    select Answer1 as Answer from AnswerTable where Id = a.Id
    union all
    select Answer2 from AnswerTable where Id = a.Id
    union all
    select Answer3 from AnswerTable where Id = a.Id
    union all
    select Answer4 from AnswerTable where Id = a.Id
  ) x
  group by Answer
  order by count(*) desc, Answer asc
) TopAnswers
```

Here's the SQLFiddle for it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1dfd/8

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at how to use apply in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to unpivot the data.  The trick is you need an `id` to identify each row.  This is obtained using `row_number()` in the following query.  Then getting the values you want requires judicious use of aggregation and window functions:

```
with t as (
      select (case when n.n = 1 then answer1
                   when n.n = 2 then answer2
                   when n.n = 3 then answer3
                   when n.n = 4 then answer4
              end) as answer, a.*
      from (select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as recnum, a.*
            from answers a
           ) cross join
           (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4) n
    )
select answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer, cnt
from (select recnum, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by recnum order by count(*) desc
                               ) as seqnum_cnt
      from t
      group by recnum, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer
     ) a
where seqnum_cnt = 1;
```